# Angular 6 component change depending on the route, Error: The selector "app-navbar" did not match any elements

Tags: angular

I have an angular application with two parts :

- One for all users, the current view
- One for admin with an admin dashboard

I want to have two different views who are managed in my app.component.html

**app.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="!isAdmin()">
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location,
  ) { }

  public getPath() {
    return this.location.path();  
  }

  public isAdmin() {
    return this.location.path().includes("/admin");
  }

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { NguCarouselModule } from '@ngu/carousel';
import { AgmCoreModule, GoogleMapsAPIWrapper } from '@agm/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { AppComponent } from '@app/app.component';
import { SharedModule } from '@app/shared/shared.module';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppRoutingModule } from '@app/app-routing.module';
import { NavbarComponent } from '@app/components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    AdminComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    SharedModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, NavbarComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

But on my application I have this error :

> ERROR Error: The selector "app-navbar" did not match any elements
>           at DefaultDomRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement
>   (platform-browser.js:1079)
>           at BaseAnimationRenderer.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/animations.js.BaseAnimationRenderer.selectRootElement
>   (animations.js:236)
>           at DebugRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugRenderer2.selectRootElement
>   (core.js:11456)
>           at createElement (core.js:8136)
>           at createViewNodes (core.js:10367)
>           at createRootView (core.js:10320)
>           at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11351)
>           at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:10838)
>           at ComponentFactory_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactory_.create
>   (core.js:8666)
>           at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create
>   (core.js:3315)

How it's possible to have the distinction between these two views with my two different navbars? I want to create to a component of the navbar, on for each view.

When i remove *ngIf="!isAdmin()" it's works fine.

Comment: Post all your modules please, probably you forgot to add the component to one of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check in which module is declared `<app-navbar>` (which module does include `AppNavbarComponent`?)
2. Check if `AppNavbarComponent` is exported in its module
3. Check if the above module is imported in `app.module.ts`

If no module is declaring `AppNavbarComponent`, then add it in the `declarations` of `app.module.ts`

Comment: yes it's declared. When i remove *ngIf="!isAdmin()" it's works fine ...

Comment: I find the problem, i import NavbarComponent in my app.module.ts inside  bootstrap: [AppComponent, NavbarComponent], i remove it from bootstrap.